# Tikz: Aligning origins of two figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, subfloats

I create two graphics but the vertical positions of the origins are not same.
How can we set them to have the same vertical level.

Here is my MWE. Also if you have any other comments for the plots, they are welcome.

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[top=20mm,bottom=20mm,left=20mm,right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\definecolor{mc1}{rgb}{0.368417,0.506779,0.709798}
\definecolor{mc2}{rgb}{0.880722,0.611041,0.142051}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
    \subfloat[The surface $z=f(x,y)$.]{\label{sespex2fig1a}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={sgn(\x)=(\x>=0)*1+(\x<=0)*(-1);f(\x,\y)=(\x<=0)*(-\y)+(\x>=0)*((abs{\y}>=\x^2)*(sgn(\y)*(sqrt{abs{\y}}+1)*\x-\y)+(abs{\y}<=\x^2)*(sgn(\y)*sqrt{abs{\y}}));}]
        \begin{axis}[
          width=100mm,
          height=60mm,
          view={120}{75},
          axis lines=center,
          xtick={-1,0,1},
          x tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          xmin=-1.25,
          xmax=1.25,
          domain=-1:1,
          xlabel={$t$},
          xlabel style={opacity=0.4},
          x axis line style={opacity=0.6},
          ytick={-1,0,1},
          y tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          ymin=-1.25,
          ymax=1.25,
          y domain=-1:1,
          ylabel={$y$},
          ylabel style={opacity=0.4},
          y axis line style={opacity=0.6},
          %ztick={-1,1},
          zticklabels={\empty},
          z tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          zmin=-0.75,
          zmax=0.75,
          zlabel={$z$},
          zlabel style={opacity=0.4},
          z axis line style={opacity=0.6},
        ]
          \addplot3[surf,color=mc1,opacity=0.2,samples=25,samples y=25,faceted color=mc1!40]{f(x,y)};
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=-1:1,samples=2,color=mc2,thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:0,\t,-\t);
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=0:1,samples=11,color=mc2,thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:\t,\t^2,\t);
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=0:1,samples=11,color=mc2,thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:\t,-\t^2,-\t);
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \qquad
    \subfloat[The parses of the domain of $f$.]{\label{sespex2fig1b}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
          width=100mm,
          height=60mm,
          view={0}{90},
          axis lines=center,
          xtick={-1,0,1},
          x tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          xmin=-1.25,
          xmax=1.25,
          domain=-1:1,
          xlabel={$t$},
          xlabel style={opacity=0.4},
          x axis line style={opacity=0.6},
          ytick={-1,0,1},
          y tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          ymin=-1.25,
          ymax=1.25,
          y domain=-1:1,
          ylabel={$y$},
          ylabel style={opacity=0.4},
          y axis line style={opacity=0.6},
          ztick={-1,1},
          zticklabels={\empty},
          z tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          zmin=-1.25,
          zmax=1.25,
          zlabel={$z$},
          zlabel style={opacity=0.4},
          z axis line style={opacity=0.6},
        ]
          \addplot3[surf,color=mc1,opacity=0.2,samples=25,samples y=25,faceted color=mc1!40]{0};
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=-1:1,samples=2,color=mc2,very thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:0,\t,0);
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=0:1,samples=11,color=mc2,thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:\t,\t^2,0);
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=0:1,samples=11,color=mc2,thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:\t,-\t^2,0);
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \caption{Graphics of $f:\R^{2}\to\R$.}\label{sespex2fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\R` is not defined. images are aligned at bottom (as is typical for any documents). try to enlarge first image (make it more tall)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see, which one below figures better fit to your expectation:

[image]

for second figure I enlarge height of the firs sub image;

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\usepackage[top=20mm,bottom=20mm,left=20mm,right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\definecolor{mc1}{rgb}{0.368417,0.506779,0.709798}
\definecolor{mc2}{rgb}{0.880722,0.611041,0.142051}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
    \subfloat[The surface $z=f(x,y)$.]{\label{sespex2fig1a}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),% <---- added
      declare function = {sgn(\x)=(\x>=0)*1+(\x<=0)*(-1);f(\x,\y)=(\x<=0)*(-\y)+(\x>=0)*((abs{\y}>=\x^2)*(sgn(\y)*(sqrt{abs{\y}}+1)*\x-\y)+(abs{\y}<=\x^2)*(sgn(\y)*sqrt{abs{\y}}));}]
        \begin{axis}[
          width=100mm,
          height=60mm,
          view={120}{75},
          axis lines=center,
          xtick={-1,0,1},
          x tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          xmin=-1.25,
          xmax=1.25,
          domain=-1:1,
          xlabel={$t$},
          xlabel style={opacity=0.4},
          x axis line style={opacity=0.6},
          ytick={-1,0,1},
          y tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          ymin=-1.25,
          ymax=1.25,
          y domain=-1:1,
          ylabel={$y$},
          ylabel style={opacity=0.4},
          y axis line style={opacity=0.6},
          %ztick={-1,1},
          zticklabels={\empty},
          z tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          zmin=-0.75,
          zmax=0.75,
          zlabel={$z$},
          zlabel style={opacity=0.4},
          z axis line style={opacity=0.6},
        ]
          \addplot3[surf,color=mc1,opacity=0.2,samples=25,samples y=25,faceted color=mc1!40]{f(x,y)};
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=-1:1,samples=2,color=mc2,thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:0,\t,-\t);
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=0:1,samples=11,color=mc2,thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:\t,\t^2,\t);
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=0:1,samples=11,color=mc2,thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:\t,-\t^2,-\t);
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \qquad
    \subfloat[The parses of the domain of $f$.]{\label{sespex2fig1b}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]% <---- added
        \begin{axis}[
          width=100mm,
          height=60mm,
          view={0}{90},
          axis lines=center,
          xtick={-1,0,1},
          x tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          xmin=-1.25,
          xmax=1.25,
          domain=-1:1,
          xlabel={$t$},
          xlabel style={opacity=0.4},
          x axis line style={opacity=0.6},
          ytick={-1,0,1},
          y tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          ymin=-1.25,
          ymax=1.25,
          y domain=-1:1,
          ylabel={$y$},
          ylabel style={opacity=0.4},
          y axis line style={opacity=0.6},
          ztick={-1,1},
          zticklabels={\empty},
          z tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          zmin=-1.25,
          zmax=1.25,
          zlabel={$z$},
          zlabel style={opacity=0.4},
          z axis line style={opacity=0.6},
        ]
          \addplot3[surf,color=mc1,opacity=0.2,samples=25,samples y=25,faceted color=mc1!40]{0};
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=-1:1,samples=2,color=mc2,very thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:0,\t,0);
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=0:1,samples=11,color=mc2,thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:\t,\t^2,0);
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=0:1,samples=11,color=mc2,thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:\t,-\t^2,0);
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \caption{Graphics of $f:\R^{2}\to\R$.}
    \label{sespex2fig1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
    \subfloat[The surface $z=f(x,y)$.]{\label{sespex2fig1a}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),% <---- added
      declare function = {sgn(\x)=(\x>=0)*1+(\x<=0)*(-1);f(\x,\y)=(\x<=0)*(-\y)+(\x>=0)*((abs{\y}>=\x^2)*(sgn(\y)*(sqrt{abs{\y}}+1)*\x-\y)+(abs{\y}<=\x^2)*(sgn(\y)*sqrt{abs{\y}}));}]
        \begin{axis}[
          width=100mm,
          height=84mm,
          view={120}{75},
          axis lines=center,
          xtick={-1,0,1},
          x tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          xmin=-1.25,
          xmax=1.25,
          domain=-1:1,
          xlabel={$t$},
          xlabel style={opacity=0.4},
          x axis line style={opacity=0.6},
          ytick={-1,0,1},
          y tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          ymin=-1.25,
          ymax=1.25,
          y domain=-1:1,
          ylabel={$y$},
          ylabel style={opacity=0.4},
          y axis line style={opacity=0.6},
          %ztick={-1,1},
          zticklabels={\empty},
          z tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          zmin=-0.75,
          zmax=0.75,
          zlabel={$z$},
          zlabel style={opacity=0.4},
          z axis line style={opacity=0.6},
        ]
          \addplot3[surf,color=mc1,opacity=0.2,samples=25,samples y=25,faceted color=mc1!40]{f(x,y)};
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=-1:1,samples=2,color=mc2,thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:0,\t,-\t);
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=0:1,samples=11,color=mc2,thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:\t,\t^2,\t);
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=0:1,samples=11,color=mc2,thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:\t,-\t^2,-\t);
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \qquad
    \subfloat[The parses of the domain of $f$.]{\label{sespex2fig1b}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]% <---- added
        \begin{axis}[
          width=100mm,
          height=60mm,
          view={0}{90},
          axis lines=center,
          xtick={-1,0,1},
          x tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          xmin=-1.25,
          xmax=1.25,
          domain=-1:1,
          xlabel={$t$},
          xlabel style={opacity=0.4},
          x axis line style={opacity=0.6},
          ytick={-1,0,1},
          y tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          ymin=-1.25,
          ymax=1.25,
          y domain=-1:1,
          ylabel={$y$},
          ylabel style={opacity=0.4},
          y axis line style={opacity=0.6},
          ztick={-1,1},
          zticklabels={\empty},
          z tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          zmin=-1.25,
          zmax=1.25,
          zlabel={$z$},
          zlabel style={opacity=0.4},
          z axis line style={opacity=0.6},
        ]
          \addplot3[surf,color=mc1,opacity=0.2,samples=25,samples y=25,faceted color=mc1!40]{0};
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=-1:1,samples=2,color=mc2,very thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:0,\t,0);
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=0:1,samples=11,color=mc2,thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:\t,\t^2,0);
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=0:1,samples=11,color=mc2,thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:\t,-\t^2,0);
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \caption{Graphics of $f:\R^{2}\to\R$.}
    \label{sespex2fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**addendum:** considering John Kormylo comments below, you can for the firs figure write:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\usepackage[top=20mm,bottom=20mm,left=20mm,right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\definecolor{mc1}{rgb}{0.368417,0.506779,0.709798}
\definecolor{mc2}{rgb}{0.880722,0.611041,0.142051}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
    \subfloat[The surface $z=f(x,y)$.]{\label{sespex2fig1a}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(origin),% <---- suggestion of John Kormylo
      declare function = {sgn(\x)=(\x>=0)*1+(\x<=0)*(-1);f(\x,\y)=(\x<=0)*(-\y)+(\x>=0)*((abs{\y}>=\x^2)*(sgn(\y)*(sqrt{abs{\y}}+1)*\x-\y)+(abs{\y}<=\x^2)*(sgn(\y)*sqrt{abs{\y}}));}]
        \begin{axis}[
          width=100mm,
          height=60mm,
          view={120}{75},
          axis lines=center,
          xtick={-1,0,1},
          x tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          xmin=-1.25,
          xmax=1.25,
          domain=-1:1,
          xlabel={$t$},
          xlabel style={opacity=0.4},
          x axis line style={opacity=0.6},
          ytick={-1,0,1},
          y tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          ymin=-1.25,
          ymax=1.25,
          y domain=-1:1,
          ylabel={$y$},
          ylabel style={opacity=0.4},
          y axis line style={opacity=0.6},
          %ztick={-1,1},
          zticklabels={\empty},
          z tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          zmin=-0.75,
          zmax=0.75,
          zlabel={$z$},
          zlabel style={opacity=0.4},
          z axis line style={opacity=0.6},
        ]
        \coordinate (origin) at (axis cs: 0,0,0); % suggestion of John Kormylo
          \addplot3[surf,color=mc1,opacity=0.2,samples=25,samples y=25,faceted color=mc1!40]{f(x,y)};
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=-1:1,samples=2,color=mc2,thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:0,\t,-\t);
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=0:1,samples=11,color=mc2,thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:\t,\t^2,\t);
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=0:1,samples=11,color=mc2,thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:\t,-\t^2,-\t);
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \qquad
    \subfloat[The parses of the domain of $f$.]{\label{sespex2fig1b}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(origin)]% <---- added
        \begin{axis}[
          width=100mm,
          height=60mm,
          view={0}{90},
          axis lines=center,
          xtick={-1,0,1},
          x tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          xmin=-1.25,
          xmax=1.25,
          domain=-1:1,
          xlabel={$t$},
          xlabel style={opacity=0.4},
          x axis line style={opacity=0.6},
          ytick={-1,0,1},
          y tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          ymin=-1.25,
          ymax=1.25,
          y domain=-1:1,
          ylabel={$y$},
          ylabel style={opacity=0.4},
          y axis line style={opacity=0.6},
          ztick={-1,1},
          zticklabels={\empty},
          z tick label style={opacity=0.4},
          zmin=-1.25,
          zmax=1.25,
          zlabel={$z$},
          zlabel style={opacity=0.4},
          z axis line style={opacity=0.6},
        ]
        \coordinate (origin) at (axis cs: 0,0,0); % suggestion of John Kormylo
          \addplot3[surf,color=mc1,opacity=0.2,samples=25,samples y=25,faceted color=mc1!40]{0};
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=-1:1,samples=2,color=mc2,very thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:0,\t,0);
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=0:1,samples=11,color=mc2,thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:\t,\t^2,0);
          \draw[variable=\t,domain=0:1,samples=11,color=mc2,thick,dashed] plot (axis cs:\t,-\t^2,0);
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \caption{Graphics of $f:\R^{2}\to\R$.}
    \label{sespex2fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

the obtained result is the same. possible advantage is that you have more flexibility where the `origin`  is in the image (not tested).

Comment: I would have used [baseline=(origin)] and \coordinate (origin) at (axis cs: 0,0,0);

Comment: @JohnKormylo Do you mind posting an answer? I dont know how I can handle it.

Comment: @bkarpuz, instead `[baseline=(current bounding box.center)...` in *mwe* you write `[baseline=(origin)]`and after definition of axes (before `\addplots`) put `\coordinate (origin) at (axis cs: 0,0,0)` . result will be the same as is shown in my answer.